# How to get organisation id & name from other than cloud resource manager API in google?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am getting organization details from the following API.

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/organizations/search

Scope : https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformorganizations.readonly

I get the response as below

```
{
  "organizations": [
    {
      "creationTime": "2017-01-19T18:42:23.202Z",
      "displayName": "xyz.com",
      "lifecycleState": "ACTIVE",
      "name": "organizations/12345678910",
      "owner": {
        "directoryCustomerId": "abc123"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To get above details, need to enable cloud resource mangar API. By enabling cloud resource manager API, we will have permission to get all information like policies about that organization, if the employee has permission.

Any other API available to get organization id & name of an employee through employee mail id?

Answer (score 0):

In relation to this part of your post:

> By enabling Cloud Resource Manager API, we will have permission to get
>   all information like policies about that organisation, if the employee
>   has permission.

This isn't completely accurate. If the Cloud Resource API is enabled, it doesn't mean all employees can access and utilise that API to it's full potential. Each user in a project is assigned permissions/roles so if you don't want users in a project to be able to use the Resource Manager API, then just ensure they are not assigned permission to do so.

Other ways of retrieving organisation and user info (with the Cloud Resource Manager API disabled) include the use of the gcloud. Using gcloud, you can retrieve information about users for a specified project, and also to discover the organisation ID of a specified  project.

To list the users and service account in a project you can run:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy PROJECT_ID
```

You can discover the organisation ID of a project by running:

```
gcloud projects describe PROJECT_ID
```

The output YAML will contain a 'parent' section which will contain an 'id' key associated with a value that contains the organisation ID. For example, it will looking something like this:

```
parent:
  id: '746874676465'
  type: organization
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it is in `gcloud`:

[How do I get the organization ID of my current project in Google Cloud Platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59749855/how-do-i-get-the-organization-id-of-my-current-project-in-google-cloud-platform)

```
gcloud projects get-ancestors $PROJ

ID                      TYPE
Your-project-ID         project
123456789012            folder
567890123456            organization
```